# How to enable/disable DHCP of eth0

Tags: networking, shell

`ifconfig eth0 dhcp start` or `ifconfig eth0 dhcp drop` does not seem to work for Android.  Is there a way to enable/disable DHCP for `eth0` via shell commands?

Comment: Do you've  the tool named `netcfg`?

Comment: @Firelord command netcfg works.  How can I use it to enable/disable DHCP?

Comment: Try with `netcfg eth0 dhcp`. See http://headlessandroid.blogspot.in/2012/06/networking-on-headless-android-system.html. Don't know how to disable DHCP.

Comment: @Firelord I have just tried that.  It did not return anything.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Comment: ifconfig eth0.15 dhcp drop 
ifconfig: bad address 'dhcp'

Answer (score 1):

try this code in android 5.1

```
ifconfig eth0 up
dhcpcd eth0
```

OR (static)

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.70.65 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

and now

```
ndc network create 100
ndc network interface add 100 eth0
ndc network route add 100 eth0 192.168.70.0/24 (gateway)
ndc network route add 100 eth0 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.2.40 192.168.2.50
ndc resolver setnetdns 100 localdomain 192.168.2.40 192.168.2.50 (dns1 dns2)
ndc network default set 100
```

Comment: dhcpcd eth0.15
dhcpcd[4415]: version 5.5.6 starting
setprop: applet not found
setprop: applet not found
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: carrier lost
setprop: applet not found
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: carrier acquired
setprop: applet not found
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: sendmsg: Cannot assign requested address
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: rebinding lease of 192.168.88.2
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: broadcasting for a lease
dhcpcd[4415]: eth0.15: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation

Answer (score 0):

try this way (My Android device worked)

DHCP IP

```
ifconfig eth0 dhcp
```

OR

```
setprop dhcp.eth0
```

OR

```
dhcpcd -k eth0
dhcpcd -n eth0
```

OR

```
netcfg eth0 dhcp
```

OR

```
getprop dhcp.eth0
```

and 
Static IP

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.70.145 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.70.254 dev eth0
```

or

```
su -c ifconfig eth0 192.168.70.145 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.70.254 dev eth0
```

Enable Ethernet

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Disable Ethernet

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

and check wlan0 static or dynamic?
my device when wlan0 is static force once set eth0 static and after set static change to dynamic

check the device ip:

```
ip addr
```

********** try this android 5.1 ****************** eth0 dhcp

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
dhcpcd -k eth0
dhcpcd -n eth0
netcfg eth0 dhcp
```